# What can we do about low upvote rates?

Tags: discussion

I just earned a Notable Question badge (2500 views) for a question that has 1 upvote. How on Earth have 2499 people viewed this question without upvoting? I guess the problem is that many people who find this site through searching won't be registered and so won't upvote. Is there anything we can do about this?

Comment: I don't think views are strongly correlated with quality.

Comment: I think last time the data was checked we have a high average of upvotes across the questions on the site, think it was on the recent question about downvotes.

Comment: The irony of this question having 56 views (as of Xmas Day 2012) and one upvote

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Voting is anonymous, and at the discretion of the voter.  There's nothing that can be done to increase, decrease, monitor, or otherwise change voters' behavior.

(Well, outside of abuses of the voting system, but that's a different topic altogether...)

There are questions with tens of thousands of views that have perhaps 1 or 2 upvotes, so this is relatively common.  Views count people who are incapable of upvoting (they lack an account or the rep to upvote) as well as those who can.  [Here's one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82300/how-do-i-breed-a-sapphire-dragon-in-dragonvale) with 40k+ views and one upvote.  Or, [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80214/how-do-you-breed-a-seasonal-dragon) with 45k+ views and *no* upvotes.  (Browsing the [Dragonvale](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonvale) tag is a good way to find a lot of these, fwiw ;)

Comment: Views also count people who aren't logged in to stack exchange.

Comment: Quite right, I'll make that clearer.

Comment: "There's nothing that can be done" is untrue.  There are already lots of badge incentives for voting, just for example, and "vote moar" drives do tend to get some short-term response.

Comment: I believe the adage goes "you can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink" :)